# Generate a list of cookies like HttpContext.Request.Cookies in a non-web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, http, cookies

I'm writing a wpf application that encrypts and decrypts cookies, using an old asp.net project as a code reference.  That web application includes a dropdown list of Cookie names avaiable to process.  That dropdown list is populated using `Controller.HttpContext.Request.Cookies`.

I want to include that functionality in my program, but i have no HttpContext to work with.  Is there a way to generate an equivalent httpcontext for this purpose?  If not, what other options do I have?  I tried looking into the folders containing cookies from ie/firefox/chrome but there were a ridiculous number of folders/files.

Comment: That's basically your only option, to go through all the cookies in your cookie folder and parse out what each one is. The `HttpContext` object holds contextual information about the current HTTP session, the request and response, that stuff. If you don't have any request/response, how could you have a context?

Comment: I was wondering if a request/response could be made just for this purpose or something of that nature.

Comment: You could attempt to mock an HttpContext object, but you'd have to fill in everything yourself. If you understand how HTTP works, you'll know cookies are sent to the server with the client request. That's how your server has a small list of them to read; the client sent them to it. You don't have a server now; you're on the client. You'll have to find the relevant cookies yourself.